# Trying to locate elements for radio button in table, but getting List Out of range error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, radio-button

```html
<tr>
    <td id="td2">
    <div id="firstDiv">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>ISOC</td>
            <td>User Id</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>User Type</td>
                        
            <td>Template</td>
                            
                    </tr>
                    
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color: rgb(10, 66, 121); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><input type="radio" class="radio" onclick= "this.form.iata_portal_entry.disabled=this.form.cancel.disabled =false;" name="login" value="iata_portal_entry.0.107AT.4354"></td>
            <td style="background-color: rgb(10, 66, 121); color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">AT</td>`
```

My code to select Radio button:-

```py
radiobuttons = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//td/input[@type='radio']")
print(radiobuttons)
radiobuttons[0].click()
```

Alternate code tried:-

```py
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='radio'][@value='iata_portal_entry.0.107AT.4354']").click()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJUMQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error you see is caused by the empty list returned by the 'find_elements' method.

Either your XPATH is not valid (it looks valid tho), or your table is in the iframe, or your page is not fully loaded.

You didn't provide a link to the target website, but in general, there shouldn't be any tricks when working with radio buttons.

Here is a simple example of handling radio buttons. It includes waiting for the elements to be present, looping over all located elements, double-checking if the element is clickable, and then doing the actual click.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

try:
    driver.get("https://qbek.github.io/selenium-exercises/en/radio_buttons.html")

    elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='radio']")))
    for el in elements:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(el)).click()
        time.sleep(1)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you see in your console when you execute `print(radiobuttons)`?

Comment: Please leave clarifications asking for extra detail as comments on the original question, not as answers.

Comment: I am getting [] and error is list out of range

Comment: @jprockbelly stackoverflow won't allow me to comment directly on the original question since I don't have enough 'reputation'

Comment: Is this `<tr>` element within a frame? If `driver.find_element(By.ID, 'td2')` doesn't return anything either (assuming there's only one element on the page with that ID), then like what @sashkins said earlier, either the elements are in an iframe or the page hasn't fully loaded